# Android WorkManager triggers doWork function randomly

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to trigger function every 3 minutes, so I've code:

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .build()

val request = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<SomeWorker>(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .setConstraints(constraints)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request)
```

And the logs (comes from doWork() function):

```
2021-07-14 12:02:29.513
2021-07-14 12:03:22.293
2021-07-14 12:03:57.856
2021-07-14 12:05:50.007
```

While I'd expect logs every 3 minutes not random interval.

Comment: WorkManager is only supposed to be used with a >15 minute interval and by nature is inexact. I think you should consider another approach.

Comment: Yes. He is right. Just use a service and just don't die. If a service is not ok - most likely you have a design problem.